# Kerberos: cannot propagate database between linux master and slave kdc's

Tags: linux, kerberos

The command

```
sudo kprop -r MY.DOMAIN -f /var/lib/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans slave_kdc.my.domain
```

returns

```
kprop: Key table entry not found while getting initial credentials
```

This is a new installation on two linux debian servers. The master_kdc seems to work, but I cannot get the database to propagate. I manually copied the database dump and loaded it onto the slave_kdc, but the propagation still does not work.

/etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN
# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true

[realms]
    MY.DOMAIN = {
            kdc = master_kdc.my.domain
            kdc = slave_kdc.my.domain
            admin_server = master_kdc.my.domain
    }
[domain_realm]
    .my.domain = MY.DOMAIN
    my.domain = MY.DOMAIN
```

/etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
    kdc_ports = 750,88

[realms]
    MY.DOMAIN = {
        database_name = /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal
        admin_keytab = FILE:/etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
        acl_file = /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
        key_stash_file = /etc/krb5kdc/stash
        kdc_ports = 750,88
        max_life = 10h 0m 0s
        max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
        master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
        #supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal
        default_principal_flags = +preauth
    }

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmin.log
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5lib.log
```

/etc/krb6kdc/kadm5/acl

```
john/admin@MY.DOMAIN        *
```

/etc/krb5kdc/kpropd.acl

```
host/master_kdc.my.domain@MY.DOMAIN
host/slave_kdc.my.domain@MY.DOMAIN
```

I installed xinetd and created the following file and enabled and started the xinetd service.
/etc/xinetd.d/krb5_prop

```
service krb5_prop
{
    disable = no
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/sbin/kpropd
}
```

result of sudo cat /etc/services | grep krb5

```
kerberos    88/tcp      kerberos5 krb5 kerberos-sec # Kerberos v5
kerberos    88/udp      kerberos5 krb5 kerberos-sec # Kerberos v5
krb5_prop   754/tcp     krb-prop krb_prop hprop # Kerberos slave propagation
```

I generated the /etc/krb5.keytab file on master_kdc and on slave_kdc after copying over the database.

```
kadmin: ktadd host/slave_kdc.my.domain
```

Nothing is being logged (I don't know why).

/etc/bind/zones/db.my.domain

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     master_kdc.my.domain. john.my.domain. (
                          5         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; Name servers - NS records
@       IN      NS      master_kdc.my.domain.
@       IN      NS      slave_kdc.my.domain.

; Name servers - A records
master_kdc  IN      A      AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1
slave_kdc  IN      A       AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2

; Kerberos services
_kerberos._udp.MY.DOMAIN.   IN      SRV     1       0       88      master_kdc.my.domain.
_kerberos._tcp.MY.DOMAIN.   IN      SRV     1       0       88      master_kdc.my.domain.
_kerberos._udp.MY.DOMAIN.   IN      SRV     10      0       88      slave_kdc.my.domain.
_kerberos._tcp.MY.DOMAIN.   IN      SRV     10      0       88      slave_kdc.my.domain.
_kerberos-adm._tcp.MY.DOMAIN.       IN      SRV     1       0       749     master_kdc.my.domain.
_kpasswd._udp.MY.DOMAIN.   IN      SRV     1       0       464      master_kdc.my.domain.
```

/etc/bind/zones/db.AAA

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     master_kdc.my.domain.   john.my.domain. (
                                    5       ; Serial
                               604800       ; Refresh
                                86400       ; Retry
                              2419200       ; Expire
                               604800 )     ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; Name servers - NS records
@       IN      NS      master_kdc.my.domain.
@       IN      NS      slave_kdc.my.domain.
master_kdc  IN      A       AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1
slave_kdc   IN      A       AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2

; Name servers - PTR records
DD1      IN      PTR     master_kdc.my.domain.
DD2      IN      PTR     slave_kdc.my.domain.
```

Comment: In your description I am missing the part were the keytabs are created and deployed. The file `/etc/krb5kdc/kpropd.acl` can have just one entry `host/master_kdc.my.domain@MY.DOMAIN`. Yes, you should get rid of the extra realms in `/etc/krb5.conf`. The file `/etc/xinetd.d/krb5_prop` should also contain an entry about the IP address of the service. In my config the service has the same name in `/etc/services` as `/etc/xinetd.d/krb5_prop`.

Comment: @U880D I edited the question to reflect light modifications and added a bit about generating the keytabs. I don't know what format to add the IP address to the xinetd.d/krb5_prop.

Comment: During my setup I've experienced the same problem and learned that DNS is very important. For all hosts hostnames, FQDNs and PTRs were necessary. The `dig` and `host` command showed the rights entries for all involved nodes. The stash file was also important, I had to check my passwords. I'll try to check my notes for a more detailed description and/or step-by-step instructions.

Comment: I have exact the same problem. Do you got a solution or have you given up? With prefixed `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kprop ...` I get additional information: `Looked up etypes in keytab: (empty)`. Yes, I have added all possible keys to the `/etc/krb5.keytab`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours to resolve this exact same issue.
Finally it was solved by this steps:

1. create master host principal " addprinc host/mastr.comain.com "
2. On master server, add to keytab the master host principal " ktadd
   host/mastr.comain.com"

Apparently kprop use "kinit -k" to get a ticket and this only work when you have your master host entry in keytab.